# how to print 3 parameters in a function in order in python

Tags: python

The question is: write a function that takes 3 parameters, and print them out in order

I am new to this, so I'd appreciated a simple function which I can understand.

For example:

```
>>> print_in_order(5,6,4)
In order: 4, 5, 6
```

I wrote:

```
def print_in_order(x,y,z):
    print "in order: ", sorted([x,y,z])
```

Then I called:

```
print_in_order(5,6,4)
```

But the outcome is

```
In order: [4,5,6]
```

I want to take the square brackets off, but still unable to figure a way out.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty tough homework assignment...have you googled sorting yet?

Comment: yip i did man, tried youtube and, of course, on here.

Comment: @jamylak this is actually an extension exercise, I have finished standard "homework", I've been trying for the past hr so thank u for assuming me being an lazy ass...

Comment: Can you break this down into some steps? First, you need to write a function that takes 3 parameters. Do you know how to do that? Next, you need to sort those numbers in order. If you don't know how to do that, can you find [python sort](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+sort) on Google? Finally, you have to print the list of numbers. Do you know how to print in Python? Whatever parts of this you don't know, you can find out, and you can find it all by searching on your own - but search the whole Web, not just YouTube and SO.

Answer (score 1):

Ok since you've shown you actually did try, I take back what I said before:

```
def print_in_order(x,y,z):
    print "in order: " + ", ".join(map(str, sorted([x,y,z])))
```

Extending this, if you want to support any number of arguments, you can use this:

```
def print_in_order(*args):
    print "in order: " + ", ".join(map(str, sorted(args)))
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but there is type error accrued
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: @user2210265 `.join(map(str, sorted([x,y,z])))`

Comment: `"{}, {}, {}".format(*sorted([x,y,z]))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_in_order(x,y,z):
    print "in order: %d, %d, %d" % tuple(sorted([x,y,z]))
```